# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 1}(2x+3)=5$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Please check my proof

There exist $\delta $ such that $0<x<\delta \rightarrow |2x+3-5|=|2x-2|<\epsilon $

$$0<x<\delta \rightarrow 2|x-1|< \epsilon $$
$$ \rightarrow |x-1|<\frac{\epsilon }{2}$$

Choose $\delta =\frac{\epsilon }{2}$

For x is real number and 
$$0<x<\delta \rightarrow |2x+3-5|=|5-5|=0<\delta =\frac{\epsilon }{2}$$

Then limit is 5

Comment: In the first line shouldn't that be $0<|x-1|<\delta$

Comment: Actually, you have to choose $\delta$ s.t. $|x-1|<\delta$.

Comment: Your choice for $\delta$ is correct.

Comment: You need to prove that $\displaystyle \mathop{\forall}_{\varepsilon >0}\mathop{\exists}_{\delta>0}\mathop{\forall}_{x\in \mathbb R}\left(|x-1|<\delta\to |(2x+3)-5|<\varepsilon\right)$. You're not doing this at all, also the bit $|2x+3-5|=|5-5|$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|f(x)-f(1)|=|2x+3-5|=2|x-1|$$

So for a given $\epsilon$ if you choose $\delta < \epsilon /2$ we will get

$$|x-1|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(1)| <\epsilon$$